# Code giving runtime error in codeforce prob 474 A

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am a beginner in codeforces. I am stuck in [problem 474 A](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/474/a) where I am getting runtime error. But I can't any fault in it. I use C. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, i, j, b, arr[102];
    char ch, str2[101], c;
    char str1[30] = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./";
    for (i = 0; i<30; i++)
        arr[(str1[i])] = i;
    scanf("%c%s", &ch, str2);
    if (ch == 'R')
    {
        for (i = 0; str2[i]; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", str1[(arr[str2[i]] - 1)]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; str2[i]; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", str1[(arr[str2[i]] + 1)]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you find what is wrong in it?

Comment: Please explain what you are supposed to do, I don't have a clue what codeforces prob 474 A is asking you to do.

Comment: `arr[(str1[i])]` accesses invalid memory locations for some values of `str[i]`.

Comment: @BobRun I've edited the post to include the link o the problem.

Comment: @Cool Guy thanks for the post, but the keyboard seems usual to me not "unusual" as the site says.

Comment: @Cool Guy about invalid mem, that would happen if I enter R then for example q because it would be before the string, but it is happening on chars that shd be translated. So I give up for now.

Comment: @BobRun "_about invalid mem, that would happen if I enter ..._" -- I was saying about `arr[(str1[i])] = i;` *before* the `scanf`. "_but it is happening on chars that shd be translated._" - Sorry. I did not get you. Did you mean that the OP uses a `char` for indexing the array?

Comment: @Coo Guy It seems the hash is not needed, I am posting a possible answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @BobRun. But i still cant find what my fault was in the code

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, if I understood the problem correctly this works.

```
// MOLE is typing to the right or to the left of  3 rows of keys
//   qwertyuiop
//   asdfghjkl;
//   zxcvbnm,./
// encoded as:   !qwertyuiop!asdfghjkl;!zxcvbnm,./!
// where '!' detects input errors

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
  int i;
  char ch;
  char str2[101];
  char kstr1[50];
  char *poschar;        // pointer to char
  int int_poschar = 0;
  int translated_position = 0;
  int right = 0;
  int left = 0;

  strcpy( kstr1, "!qwertyuiop!asdfghjkl;!zxcvbnm,./!" );

  printf( "\n Please enter R or L and press enter\n" );

  scanf( " %c ", &ch );
  ch = toupper( ch );

  if ( ch == 'R' || ch == 'L' ) ; // good input say nothing
  else
  {
    printf( "\nPlease try again with L or R  ( or l or r ) " );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  printf( "\n Please enter a word and press enter\n" );

  scanf( " %100s", str2 );
  strcpy( str2, strlwr( str2 ) );

  if ( ch == 'R' )
  {
    printf( "\nRIGHT translate:\n%s\n", str2 );
    right = 1;
  }
  else if ( ch == 'L' )
  {
    printf( "\nLEFT translate:\n%s\n", str2 );
    left = 1;
  }

  getchar(  );

  for ( i = 0; str2[i]; i++ )
  {
    poschar = strchr( kstr1, str2[i] );
    if ( poschar != NULL )
    {
      int_poschar = poschar - kstr1;    // find prev pos in array

      if ( right )
    translated_position = int_poschar - 1;
      else if ( left )
    translated_position = int_poschar + 1;
      else
      {
    printf( "\n you've got a bug !" );
    exit( 0 );
      }

      if ( kstr1[translated_position] == '!' )
      {
    if ( right )
      printf( "\n not possible, MOLE wrote 1 key to the right" );
    else
      printf( "\n not possible, MOLE wrote 1 key to the left" );

    getchar(  );
    exit( 0 );
      }
      printf( "%c", kstr1[int_poschar - 1] );
    }               // endif ( poschar != NULL )

  }
  exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution(although have not understood it completely though. beginner coder)

Comment: At first your code looks great and the hash function works. Then you read it again and you find that your logic is wrong [ when MOLE types to the right of P he is not typing A] and the hash is not speeding anything but making everything more complicated. That's when you need to start fresh. My code here is only one of many possible solutions and is not perfect. If you don't understand it, try reading again, write it down by hand, break it, make it crash. Then restart on a brand new solution, one that you understand, that's how we learn.